# Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Tags: c, stack, char

Estou fazendo um programa pra uma finalidade simples: Pegar uma frase e transformar ela em um versão dela com os caracteres de cada palavra isolada ao contrario, como: "Estou com problemas" viraria "uotsE moc samelborp". Ao compilar com gcc questao1.c -o q1 -g, escrever gdb ./q1 e dar run, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554836 in pilha_push (p=0x555555757010, v=101 'e') at questao1.c:23
23  p->c[p->topo] = v;
```

Já olhei em muitos lugares e nada me foi útil.
Segue o código:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int N = 50;

typedef struct pilha{
        char *c;
        int topo;
}Pilha;

Pilha* pilha_cria(void)
{
Pilha* p = (Pilha*) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
p->topo = 0;
return p;
}

void pilha_push (Pilha* p, char v)
{
if (p->topo == N) {
printf("Capacidade da pilha estourou.\n");
exit(1);
}
p->c[p->topo] = v;
p->topo++;
}

void inverte_palavra(char c[], int n){
      char c1[n];
      int i=0;
      for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
                          c1[i] = c[n-i];
      }
      i=0;
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                   printf("%c", c1[n]);
  }
}
void zerar_char(char c[], int n){
 char c1[n];
 c = c1;
}
void inverter_pilha(Pilha *p){
 int n = 0;
 int i=0;
 char c1[p->topo];
 for(i = 0; i<p->topo;i++){
       if(p->c[i] != ' '){
               c1[i] = p->c[i];
               n++;
       }else{
                   inverte_palavra(c1, n);
                   n = 0;
                   zerar_char(c1, p->topo);
       }
 }
}

int main(){

Pilha *p;
p = pilha_cria();
pilha_push(p, 'e');
pilha_push(p, 's');
pilha_push(p, 't');
pilha_push(p, 'a');
pilha_push(p, ' ');
pilha_push(p, 'p');
pilha_push(p, 'r');
pilha_push(p, 'o');
pilha_push(p, 'v');
pilha_push(p, 'a');
inverter_pilha(p);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o ponteiro `p->c` aponta para um lugar indefinido, ao tentar gravar o dado `v` na posição `p->topo`, seu programa acessou uma posição de memória "proibida" e recebeu um sinal de "Falha de Segmentação".

Na função `pilha_cria()`, você alocou uma `Pilha`, mas não alocou memoria para acomodar os seus itens no endereço de `p->c`.

Segue um exemplo (testado e melhorado) de como fazer seu programa funcionar corretamente:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct pilha {
    char *c;
    int tam;
    int topo;
} Pilha;

Pilha* pilha_cria(int tam)
{
    Pilha * p = (Pilha*) calloc( 1, sizeof(Pilha) );
    p->c = (char*) calloc( tam, sizeof(char) );
    p->topo = 0;
    p->tam = tam;
    return p;
}

void pilha_destruir(Pilha*p)
{
    free(p->c);
    free(p);
}

void pilha_push(Pilha* p, char v){
    if (p->topo < p->tam){
        p->c[ p->topo++ ] = v;
    }
}

void inverter_pilha(Pilha *p){
    int i = 0;
    int n = p->topo;
    for( i=0; i<n/2; i++){
        char aux = p->c[i];
        p->c[i] = p->c[n-1-i];
        p->c[n-1-i] = aux;
    }
}

void exibir_pilha(Pilha *p){
    int i=0;
    for(i=p->topo-1; i>=0; i--){
        printf("    [%d] %c\n", i, p->c[i]);
    }
}


int main( void ){
    Pilha * p = NULL;

    p = pilha_cria( 5 );

    pilha_push(p, 'A');
    pilha_push(p, 'E');
    pilha_push(p, 'I');
    pilha_push(p, 'O');
    pilha_push(p, 'U');

    printf("PILHA ORIGINAL:\n");
    exibir_pilha(p);

    inverter_pilha( p );

    printf("PILHA INVERTIDA:\n");
    exibir_pilha(p);

    pilha_destruir( p );
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
PILHA ORIGINAL:
    [4] U
    [3] O
    [2] I
    [1] E
    [0] A
PILHA INVERTIDA:
    [4] A
    [3] E
    [2] I
    [1] O
    [0] U
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, literalmente foi a minha solução. Acho que não fui muito claro quanto ao objetivo do programa o que pode ter te causado uma confusão: A ideia não era inverter toda a pilha e sim inverter as palavras isoladas da pilha. Então peguei seu programa e, baseado nele, acrescentei o necessário para tal objetivo:
https://pastebin.com/tMxGncB7
(Ainda não sei mexer muito bem com o stack overflow, então upei pro pastebin por ser mais simples pra colocar códigos inteiros)

Answer (score 1):

Você esqueceu de alocar `p->c` na função criadora de `Pilha`s, a `pilha_cria`. Como esse valor está vindo de uma área de memória alocada cruamente, ela terá necessariamente lixo de memória. Ocasionalmente esse lixo pode hipoteticamente falando apontar para um lugar que não estoure a exceção de falha de segmentação, mas isso é sorte.

Para corrigir, você pode definir na estrutura `char c[50]` **OU EXCLUSIVO** então, caso insista em usar memória dinâmica para esse trecho, no final de `pilha_cria`, chamar `p->c = (char*) calloc(sizeof(char), N);`

> não misture ambas as abordagens acima; elas resolvem o problema de maneiras distintas e imiscíveis, tentar usá-las em conjunto gerará erro de compilação

O `calloc` vai alocar o espaço necessário com os bytes todos zerados, então creio que isso evite alguma porventura sujeira indesejada em `p->c` que pode gerar algum bug de difícil captura.

---

Aproveitando, sua função `zerar_char` não tem o efeito colateral desejado, sendo realmente inócua. O jeito como você está armazenando a palavra a ser invertida também está estranho, até mesmo errado. Tente zerar o índice de trabalho de `c1` toda vida que você alcançar um ponto de inversão. Note também que, se a última letra não for espaço, não ocorrerá a inversão da última palavra, então seria adequado detectar casos assim e fazer a inversão ao final da última palavra armazenado em `p->c`.

Aproveitando mais uma vez, a estrutura que você está criando não é exatamente uma pilha: ela não segue o princípio LIFO, mas parece seguir FIFO (propriedade de fila). Evite usar nomes que denominam certos conceitos em situações distintas dos conceitos originais, isso vai gerar confusão e dificuldade de leitura.

---

Outro ponto interessante: é mais costumeiro em [c](/questions/tagged/c) declarar essas constantes mágicas numéricas como o seu `N` como sendo diretivas de pré-processamento; por exemplo, poderia se usar o seguinte no lugar de `int N = 50;`:

```
#define SIZE_MAX_PILHA 50
```

Cada abordagem tem suas características, cabe a você, como programador, distinguir. Como seu número `N` parecia uma constante mágica, sugeri deixar esse exemplo de **boa prática** (para desespero do @Maniero B-]) para que você possa refletir sobre o assunto no futuro.

Comment: Ao implementar o que foi recomendado, os seguintes erros surgiram:
questao1.c: In function ‘pilha_cria’:
questao1.c:13:6: error: assignment to expression with array type
 p->c = (char*) calloc(sizeof(char), N);
      ^
questao1.c: In function ‘pilha_push’:
questao1.c:24:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 p->c[p->topo] = v;
               ^
questao1.c:49:26: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
                    c1[i] = p->c[i];

Comment: esse erro aqui não foi enviado:
questao1.c: In function ‘inverter_pilha’:
questao1.c:48:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
            if(p->c[i] != ' ' && i<p->topo-1){
                       ^~

Comment: E obrigado pelas dicas, foram muito úteis pra melhorar me entendimento. Sobre a pilha se parecer com uma fila: isso provavelmente foi porque eu não implementei um método de remoção de elementos, mas isso foi pelo fato de o problema não exigir uma política de remoção mesmo.

Comment: Você mudou a estrutura **E** chamou o `calloc`?

Comment: Sobre pedantismo de nomenclatura, creio que não seja o melhor lugar para discutir, creio que talvez seja melhor no chat, em um outro dia.

Comment: @J.Gaidzinski alterei minha resposta para deixar claro que: ou exclusivo usa a alternativa de `char c[50]`, ou exclusivo usa a alternativa do `calloc`